# Node.js POST request coming back as "{}"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Started using node.js and trying the use the POST request with a fetch but when I run it, it just comes back as {} in the console
Server side code -->

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()



app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening at 3000"))
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(express.json())



app.post("/api", (request,response) => {
    console.log("Made the POST")
    console.log(request.body)
})
```

the fetch -->

```
async function submitValues(){
    const start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    const end = document.getElementById("end").value
    // console.log(start,end)
    // findShortestPath(graph, start, end)
    data = {start, end}
    
    options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"applcation/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        
    }
    
    await fetch("/api", options);
    
    
}
```

This is what i've written but just cant figure it out

Comment: its `application/json"`

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(request)`?

Comment: do you have other middlewares attached after the .post?

Comment: I get a huge amount of text in the console

Comment: your `post` api callback is returning nothing and you need body-parser

Comment: You need a body-parser https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: How would I go about adding a body-parser

Comment: he does not need body parser, he already use the built in body parser from express `express.json()`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install Node.js body parsing middleware:

```
$ npm install --save body-parser
```

and then:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: he needs a body parser, since he logs "request.body", why did you give me -1 :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/api", (request,response) => {
    console.log("Made the POST")
    console.log(request.body)
})
```

This method doesn't return anything, so not sure why you're surprised this API returns nothing.